# Ruby, how to parse csv file with multiple row data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so given this csv file

```
User Data,,
name,age,gender
jhon,15,male
nat,14,female
,,,
Item Data,,
id,name,
1,book,
```

what i want is it will looks like

```
user_data=[{name: 'jhon', age: '15', gender: 'male'},{}]
item_data=[{id: 1, name: 'book'},{}]
```

how do i do that on ruby, as far as i know is using `CSV` library. but it parse only the first row to be detected as header. but in this case i have 2 kind of header which is `user data` and `item data`. im using ruby on rails to input the csv file to databases using rake task

Comment: Do you literally want empty hashes, and for "nat" to be discarded? If not, please edit your question so that `user_data` and `item_date` are complete and correct for the contents of the file in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input = 'User Data,,
name,age,gender
jhon,15,male
nat,14,female
,,,
Item Data,,
id,name,
1,book,'
```

Just split it manually and then proceed:

```
input.
  split(/#{$/},,,#{$/}/).          # split into multiple CSVs
  map do |csv|
    head, *csv = csv.split($/)     # extract CSV titles
    {head[/.*?(?=,)/].downcase.gsub(' ', '_') => csv.join($/)} 
  end.
  reduce(&:merge).                  # make one hash
  map { |k, v| [k, CSV.parse(v)] }. # proceed with prepared CSVs
  to_h
#⇒ {"user_data"=>
#     [["name", "age", "gender"],
#      ["jhon", "15", "male"],
#      ["nat", "14", "female"]],
#   "item_data"=>
#     [["id", "name", nil],
#      ["1", "book", nil]]}
```

---

To get an array of hashes:

```
_.transform_values do |v|
  v[1..-1].map { |row| v.first.zip(row).to_h }
end
#⇒ {"user_data"=>[
#     {"name"=>"jhon", "age"=>"15", "gender"=>"male"},
#     {"name"=>"nat", "age"=>"14", "gender"=>"female"}],
#   "item_data"=>[
#     {"id"=>"1", "name"=>"book", nil=>nil}]}
```

Comment: i see this is an interesting solution. will check this out. so basically we don't need the csv library again.

Comment: you still need Ruby's CSV @MUmarRamadhana

Comment: @MUmarRamadhana yes, you might safely get rid of ruby CSV in approximately 100% of CSV parsing code. Instead of `CSV.parse(v)` you might easily `split` the strings by commas yourself.

Comment: code golfing much. Change the specs and you need to rewrite mostly everything. Whereas a parser is more robust to changes as it represents the domain logic. Just saying. Nothing against the code.

Comment: Ya so i keep using the parser as it is easier, and some of my data also contain coma in its characters which will break the specs. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Ruby CSV doesn't have that functionality, you'd need to implement that logic yourself as CSV is just raw data, it has no way to tell what is a header and what isn't.

In your case, I see you have an empty row before the next 'section', that should make your logic easier. A good place to put this logic is extending the `CSV` to support your multiple headers, something like

```
class CSV
  def parse_with_multiple_headers
    ...
  end
end
```

Also for ease of parsing I'd remove `User Data` and `Item Data` and only leave the headers:

```
name,age,gender
jhon,15,male
nat,14,female
,,,
id,name,
1,book,
```

EDIT

This is a small program that would do what you want. There's a huge room for improvement, but you get the point:

```
require 'csv'

def is_empty(row)
  row["name"] == nil && row["age"] == nil && row["gender"] == nil ? true : false
end

def csv_multiple_headers(data)
  users, items, p_users = [], [], true
  data.each do |row|
    # control write to
    if is_empty(row) 
      p_users = false
      next
    end

    # skip next header row
    row["name"] == "id" ? next : nil

    if p_users
      users.push({"name": row['name'],"age": row['age'],"gender": row['gender']})
    else
      items.push({"id": row["name"], "name": row["age"]})
    end

  end
  puts users
  puts items
end

src = "name,age,gender
jhon,15,male
nat,14,female
,,,
id,name,
1,book,
"

csv = CSV.parse(src, :headers => true)
csv_multiple_headers(csv)
```

Comment: What if there are 42 columns in the CSV?

Comment: One does not need to reimplement the parser. One needs to implement a splitter only, you might check my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for the following structure with any new headers and values:

```
require 'csv'

input = 'User Data,,
name,age,gender
jhon,15,male
nat,14,female
,,,
Item Data,,
id,name,
1,book,'

output_array = input.split(/,,,/).map do |named_csv|
  name, csv = named_csv.split(/,,/).map(&:strip)
  rows = CSV.parse(csv)
  header = rows.shift

  rows_collection = rows.map { |row| header.zip(row).to_h }

  [name, rows_collection]
end

output_hash = output_array.to_h
user_data = output_hash.fetch('User Data')
item_data = output_hash.fetch('Item Data')

puts 'user_data: ' + user_data.to_s
puts 'item_data: ' + item_data.to_s

output> user_data: [{"name"=>"jhon", "age"=>"15", "gender"=>"male"}, {"name"=>"nat", "age"=>"14", "gender"=>"female"}]
output> item_data: [{"id"=>"1", "name"=>"book", nil=>nil}]
```

To avoid `nil` values you can add `compact` method call before `zip`.

Comment: How is it different from what I have posted 1 hour ago (save for it uses hardcoded values and does not work with 3+ CSVs in the file)?

Comment: Take a look on output - topic starter requested collection and not array of arrays in result.

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

Here is the data from the question, but is rearranged somewhat (for a reason that will be made clear).

```
data =<<_
input = 'Item Data,,
id,name,
1,book,'
,,,
User Data,,
name,age,gender
jhon,15,male
nat,14,female
_
```

Let's write it to file.

```
FNAME = 'temp.csv'
File.write(FNAME, data)
  #=> 98
```

We need to specify the order of blocks of data in the file so that the variables `user_data` and `item_data` are assigned correctly.

```
order = ['user data', 'item data']
```

**Step 1: Clean and organize the data**

The file is a bit of a [dog's breakfast](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-dog-s-breakfast). It needs cleaning and reordering. This should be viewed as a separate first step. The goal here is to construct an array of stings that are in the form that allows us to use `CSV` methods to construct the (array of) arrays of hashes of interest.

```
csv_data = File.read(FNAME).
  gsub(/\Ainput =\s+\'|\,+\'?$/, '').
  split(/(?<=\n)\n/).
  sort_by { |s| order.index(s.downcase[/\A.+?$/]) }.
  map { |s| s.sub(/\A.+?\n/, '') }
    #=> ["name,age,gender\njhon,15,male\nnat,14,female\n",
    #    "id,name\n1,book\n"]
```

**Step 2: Use CSV methods to obtain the desired result**

We may now use [CSV methods](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) to obtain the desired result.

```
require 'csv'

user_data, item_data =
  csv_data.map { |s| CSV.parse(s, headers: true, converters: :numeric,
    header_converters: :symbol).map { |row| row.to_a.to_h } }
  #=> [[{:name=>"jhon", :age=>15, :gender=>"male"},
  #     {:name=>"nat", :age=>14, :gender=>"female"}],
  #    [{:id=>1, :name=>"book"}]]

user_data
  #=> [{:name=>"jhon", :age=>15, :gender=>"male"},
  #    {:name=>"nat", :age=>14, :gender=>"female"}]
item_data
  #=> [{:id=>1, :name=>"book"}]]
```

**The steps for cleaning and organizing the data**

Three regular expressions will be used for this task.

```
r1 = /
     \A               # match the beginning of the string
     input[ ]=[ ]+\' # match 'input =', then >= 1 spaces then a single quote
     |                # or
     \,+              # match >= 1 commas
     \'?              # optionally match a single quote
     $                # match the end of the line
     /x               # free-spacing regex definition mode

r2 = /
     (?<=\n) # match a newline in a positive lookbehind
     \n      # match a newline
     /x

r3 = /
     \A   # match the beginning of the string
     .+?  # match > 0 characters, lazily
     \n   # match newline
     /x

a = File.read(FNAME)
  #=> "input = 'Item Data,,\n...female\n"
b = a.gsub(r1, '')
  #=> "Item Data\nid,name\n1,book\n\nUser Data\n
  #    name,age,gender\njhon,15,male\nnat,14,female\n"
```

(I've arbitrarily broken the above return value (string) to improve readability.)

```
c = b.split(r2)
  #=> ["Item Data\nid,name\n1,book\n",
  #    "User Data\nname,age,gender\njhon,15,male\nnat,14,female\n"]
d = c.sort_by { |s| order.index(s.downcase[r3].chomp) }
  #=> ["User Data\nname,age,gender\njhon,15,male\nnat,14,female\n",
  #    "Item Data\nid,name\n1,book\n"]
csv_data = d.map { |s| s.sub(r3, '') }
  #=> ["name,age,gender\njhon,15,male\nnat,14,female\n",
  #    "id,name\n1,book\n"]
```

**Steps used to construct the arrays of hashes**

```
enum = csv_data.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["name,age,gender\njhon,15,male\nnat,14,female\n",
  #                  "id,name\n1,book\n"]:map>
```

The first element of `enum` is generated and passed to the block, and the block variable`s` is assigned its value.

```
s = enum.next
  #=> "name,age,gender\njhon,15,male\nnat,14,female\n"
```

The block calculations are now performed.

```
csv_tbl = CSV.parse(s, headers: true, converters: :numeric,
                       header_converters: :symbol)
  #=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3>
```

In the following I've added a `puts` statement to display the values of intermediate calculatons.

```
user_data = csv_tbl.map do |row|
  puts "row=#{row.inspect}, row.to_a=#{row.to_a}"
  row.to_a.to_h
end
  #=> [{:name=>"jhon", :age=>15, :gender=>"male"},
  #    {:name=>"nat", :age=>14, :gender=>"female"}]
```

The following is printed. (I've added newlines to avoid the need for the reader to scroll horizontally.)

```
row=#<CSV::Row name:"jhon" age:15 gender:"male">,
  row.to_a=[[:name, "jhon"], [:age, 15], [:gender, "male"]]
row=#<CSV::Row name:"nat" age:14 gender:"female">,
  row.to_a=[[:name, "nat"], [:age, 14], [:gender, "female"]]
```

Next, the calculation of `item` begins as follows.

```
s = enum_outer.next
  #=> "id,name\n1,book\n"
```

The remaining calculations are similar to those for computing `user_data`.

**Advantages of two-step approach**

One important reason for doing this in two steps is to simplify debugging. The initial testing of the first step is visual and can be done line-by-line. The second step is straightward once the data is in the appropriate format.

Also, should the format of the file change in future, only the first step must be revised.